# Which of the $43,380$ possible nets for a dodecahedron is the narrowest?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

I want to fit multiple regular [dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron) nets on to an infinitely long roll of paper. I want this to result in the largest possible dodecahedrons, for a roll of a given width.

My hunch is that the longer and narrower the net, the larger the dodecahedron I can produce; proving this one way or the other might be an interesting side-exercise.

My main question for now is simply: for a given size of pentagon, which of the [$43,380$ possible nets](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dodecahedron.html) for a regular dodecahedron fits into the narrowest rectangle?

Comment: In my answer I interpreted your request as "find the rectangle of smallest area". Are you instead looking for the narrowest rectangle, doesn't matter how long it is?

Comment: Yes, the narrowest, not the smallest area. I want to make the biggest dodecahedron possible for a strip of given width.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Okay, I guess my question was still not totally unambiguous. When I said 'a strip of paper', I meant to suggest that the *length* of the strip (which is what you've focused on in the edited answer) is irrelevant; I'm only interested in the width, which is to say the shorter dimension of the rectangle.

Comment: I don't understand: 4.02874 is precisely the length of the shortest side of the rectangle.

Comment: Anyway, you can find [here](http://www.al.ics.saitama-u.ac.jp/horiyama/research/unfolding/r04.pdf) a picture of all the 43380 possible nets of a dodecahedron: you can check there if you can find a net narrower than the one I proposed.

Comment: As a matter of fact I was wrong: the strip can be narrowed a little, see my second edit.

Comment: Thanks @Aretino, and apologies for misunderstanding you - yes, your post was aiming to minimise the dimension I had in mind, but as you've established yourself, it's definitely not the optimal solution. I couldn't find a list of all the nets, so your link is much appreciated! I suspect your second-edit net is still not the narrowest, but I could be wrong...

Comment: Tiny TeX aside: If you put the comma inside brackets, you don't get a space. I.e., "43{,}380" comes out as $43{,}380$ instead of $43,380$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just as a starter, I propose the most obvious one. Area of rectangle is 32.89 if every edge of dodecahedron is of unit length.

[image]

EDIT.

If one is interested in the narrowest possible net, I think the above disposition is still the best one. Because the central "belt" of six pentagons (yellow in the picture below) cannot be altered without widening the net, and the other surrounding pentagons can be moved to other positions, but this doesn't narrow (at best) the witdth of the net (see possible new positions, in blue, of three pentagons). The width of this net is $\sqrt{5+2\sqrt5}(3+\sqrt5)/4\approx4.02874$ times the length of a single edge.

[image]

EDIT 2.

Inspired by net n° 9383 in [Horiyama's list](http://www.al.ics.saitama-u.ac.jp/horiyama/research/unfolding/r04.pdf) I could find a strip slightly narrower than the above, at the expense of having its border not parallel to any pentagon side (see picture). Its width is $\approx 3.93448$.

[image]

EDIT 3.

Oolong discovered the best candidate, up to now: it is n° 43362 in the catalogue, corresponding to a width $\approx 3.66547$.

[image]

EDIT 4.

Oolong discovered an even narrower net: it is n° 36753 in the catalogue, corresponding to a width $\approx 3.3166$.
[image]

EDIT 5.

I performed an exhaustive search, using Mathematica and the complete collection of dodecahedron net centers in Mathematica format, which can be found at Horiyama's site. For every net I checked all the lines passing through two vertices: in case all the other vertices lied on the same side of the line, I then computed the distance from the line to the farthest vertex. The shortest of those distances is the "width" of the net.

Here are a few of the best results.

```
WIDTH     NET NUMBERS
3.07768   41382, 32924, 32920, 32511, 32494, 32492

3.26889   26440, 23967, 23620, 20027, 19706, 19668

3.3166    42665, 42591, 42549, 42546, 39271, 39268, 36753, 36743, 36717,
          36716, 36607, 36598, 36581, 36445, 36439, 36408, 36390, 36304,
          36298, 36267, 36264, 36263, 29579, 28755, 28742, 28741, 28740,
          28734, 28496, 28489, 28488, 28456, 28434, 28433, 28432, 28416,
          27807, 27806, 27805, 27729, 27728, 27727, 27674, 27673, 27672
```

Notice that the narrowest width can be computed exactly:
$3.07768=\sqrt{5+2\sqrt5}$.
Here's a picture of n° 41382, which is one of the "winners":
[image]

EDIT 6.

Here's the Mathematica code I used.

```
(* some definitions *)
lato=2Sin[Pi/5]//Simplify;
sqdist[a_,b_]:=(a-b).(a-b);
rot[a_,b_,t_]:=b+{{Cos[t],-Sin[t]},{Sin[t],Cos[t]}}.(a-b);
cross2[{ax_,ay_},{bx_,by_},{cx_,cy_}]:=(ax*by-ay*bx+bx*cy-cx*by+
      cx*ay-cy*ax)/Sqrt[sqdist[{ax,ay},{bx,by}]];

(* main loop; "r04_n.math" are Horiyama's files *)
all={};
Do[
  file="/path/r04_"<>ToString[n]<>".math";
  Get[file];
  net={};

  Do[
    If[sqdist[p[[i]],p[[k]]]==a^2//Simplify,
      cmid=p[[i]]+(p[[k]]-p[[i]])/a;
      start=rot[cmid,p[[i]],Pi/5]//Simplify;
      pent=Table[rot[start,p[[k]],2j*Pi/5]//FullSimplify,{j,0,5}];
      net=Append[net,pent];
      pent=Table[rot[start,p[[i]],2j*Pi/5]//FullSimplify,{j,0,5}];
      net=Append[net,pent]
      ],
    {i,1,Length[p]-1},
    {k,i+1,Length[p]}];

  pts=Flatten[net,1]//N;
  pts=Union[pts,SameTest -> (sqdist[#1,#2]<0.00001&)];

  best=1000;
  Do[
    wid=-1;
    flag=True;
    Do[
      t=cross2[pts[[i]],pts[[j]],pts[[k]]];
      If[Abs[t]<0.0000001,Continue[]];
      If[wid<0,wid0=Sign[t];wid=0];
      If[t*wid0<-0.0000001,flag=False;Break[]];
      If[Abs[t]>Abs[wid],wid=Abs[t]],
      {k,1,Length[pts]}];

    If[flag && wid/lato<best,best=wid/lato],
    {i,1,Length[pts]-1},
    {j,i+1,Length[pts]}];

  AppendTo[all,{n,best}],

  {n,1,43380}];

allsorted=Sort[all,#1[[2]]<#2[[2]]&]
```

Comment: Oh, sure ... That's great for a rectangle that's narrow *top-to-bottom*. But what if we want a rectangle that's narrow *left-to-right*? :)    [(joke)](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/609530/409)

Comment: Hmm… Maybe I misinterpreted the request of the OP...

Comment: Just replace your area calculation with a ratio. :)

Comment: Great edit with addition of 9383 and the linked to the exhaustive list… I wonder if that _is_ the narrowest possible?

Comment: Possibly promising: 43362, 43224, 43172, 42665, 42591, 42546.

Will investigate properly later, but I *think* 43,362 has a total width less than three times the length of each side. This is nice: http://www.al.ics.saitama-u.ac.jp/horiyama/research/unfolding/catalog/regular/?type=r04

Comment: I take it back, I mis-measured. I think 43,362 has a ratio of 3.625, in common with 36,753.

Comment: Very good! According to GeoGebra, the ratio is 3.66547. I'll add the picture to my answer.

Comment: I think 36753 is even better, actually. But perhaps we need to be a bit more rigorous about exploring the possibilities...

Comment: You are right: it has a width of 3.3166, I'll add the picture for the record. As for being more rigorous, the only sensible approach would be to explore EVERY net by means of a computer program. I could try that with Mathematica when I have time, I'll look at the code on Horiyama's site.

Comment: Thanks so much @Aretino, greatly appreciated! Of course, now I'm idly wondering which icosahedron nets are the narrowest...

Comment: Any chance you could post or link to your code? I'd like to compute the best net for laying out on 11x17, which is a calculation with some similarities (and some differences, since given a net, it's not quite clear how to rotate it to fit on the page.)

Comment: @GlenWhitney I added the (uncommented) Mathematica code, but I cannot find Horiyama's files and the link I gave isn't working at the moment.

Comment: This link: https://www.al.ics.saitama-u.ac.jp/horiyama/research/unfolding/ works for me, and the last link on that page is for a compressed file of all of the net layouts.

Comment: It appears that the links to Hiroyama's website are broken now. Is the list still available anywhere?