# Distinguish Length vs. Breadth in Cuboid

Tags: geometry

Cuboid has 3 pairs of parallel faces. So we have 3 types of lengths: length, breadth and height, which are used for finding its volume as *l×b×h* (the first initials).

**My notions**

- Height of cuboid is with respect to horizontal (xy) plane or base and
  above it (along +z-axis).
- Breadth is the horizontal length as seen in (arbitrarily chosen) Front View of the cuboid.
- Length is the distance between two points or two parallel faces/planes.

**My Questions**

- Is my notion OK? If not, **define** & distinguish clearly.
- Which edges should be assigned with labels 'length' and 'breadth'?
- If you are given a *2 m × 3 m × 5 m* cuboid, what is its breadth?

You may find the question trivial, but setting up unambiguous and standard practices in maths and physics is my concern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you be willing to accept that a cuboid must have one vertex at the origin and edges all parallel to coordinate axes? In this case, all cuboids take the form $[0, w] \times [0, b] \times [0, h]$, and you can define the width as the length of any edge parallel to the $x$-axis, etc. I don't see any way around arbitrariness, unless you specify the position, or at least orientation.

Comment: I don't think there is a universally accepted convention. You could insist the length be the largest of the three numbers, breadth the second largest, height the smallest. That's simple and unambiguous (except in case of ties).

Comment: This kind of question always makes me think of [these jokes](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/609530/409).

Comment: For us, we understand all are equals and can laugh at jokes. But if you write code for geometry simulation, you want computer to understand the difference among all these lengths to produce correct results.

@GerryMyerson Thanks. But don't you think smallest number for height conflicts with taller objects.